# Why does $10^{k} - 10^{k - 1} = 9 \cdot 10^{k - 1}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

I'm having trouble making sense of this.

Again why does:

$$10^{k} - 10^{k - 1} = 9 \cdot 10^{k - 1}$$

Comment: factor $10^{k-1}$ out of $10^k-10^{k-1}$

Comment: Try factoring out $10^{k-1}$.

Comment: Write $10^k = 10\cdot 10^{k-1}$ then factor out $10^{k-1}$

Comment: Hi! You can factor a $10^{k-1}$ out of the LHS. HTH!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$10^k-10^{k-1}=10^{k-1}(10-1)=9\cdot10^{k-1}$

Answer (score 7):

Factoring $10^k-10^{k-1}=10^{k-1}(10-1)$.